# Ul, Li not hidden

Tags: html, css, media

I have a problem with this so the page is less than 900 px does not hide nav ul li.
Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qExAG/
Please help. Thanks

Comment: It is pretty hard to understand what you want is this what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4y3mm/1/ ?

Comment: I don't see "display: none" for nav tag in your code. Please add it, so you can hide your nav ul li.

Comment: Next time, use the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) or any other CSS validator you like better.  Most CSS IDEs, like [Eclipse WTP](http://eclipse.org/webtools/sse/), have a built-in CSS syntax checker.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in your question. Please read this advice on how to [ask] good questions and Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  #menu {display: none;}
}
```

Do not put `;` after `px` for media queries (line 184 in your CSS code).

```
@media (max-width: 900px;) //not works
@media (max-width: 900px) //works
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wlpIj/